# Select2 options not getting updated properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm trying to build `Country -> State -> City` feature in my website where `state` and `city` select boxes are `disabled` and once user chooses a `Country` it shows that country's respective states and so on.

Issue I'm facing is that once a particular country's states are shown in state input and after that if i change the country then that new country's states are also shown but along with previous country's states.

```
function states_data(loc_data, selectedCountry) {
    var _states_array = [];
    var states = loc_data[selectedCountry];
    for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        _states_array.push({
            id: states[i],
            text: states[i]
        })
    }
    return _states_array
}

function _cities(state) {
    var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    return [{
        id: val + state,
        text: val + state
    }];
}
var loc_data = {
    'USA': ['USA State 1', 'USA State 2', 'USA State 3'],
    'Australia': ['AUS State 1', 'AUS State 2']
}

$('#loc_state').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    disabled: true
}).on('change', function() {
    var selectedState = $(this).val();
    $('#loc_city').select2({
        disabled: false,
        placeholder: "Select a city",
        allowClear: true,
        data: _cities(selectedState)  //it should delete previous values and update new ones.
    });
}).trigger('change');

$('#loc_city').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a city",
    disabled: true
});

var countries_data = [];
for (var key in loc_data) {
    countries_data.push({
        id: key,
        text: key
    });
}

$('#loc_country').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a country",
    allowClear: true,
    data: countries_data
}).on('change', function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
    $('#loc_state').select2({
        disabled: false,
        placeholder: "Select a state",
        allowClear: true,
        data: states_data(loc_data, selectedCountry) //it should delete previous values and update new ones.
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

If you select `USA` then USA's states are displayed but if you change it to `Australia` then `Australia's` states are shown but `USA's` are also there, they are not being deleted at all.

What could be the issue?

And how do i remove all choice from `State` and `City` if a a user unselects `Country` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change to get it working using your code is to `.empty()` before re-initializing.

`.empty()` will remove all the options currently in the select then when you re-initializing it will add the new items.

```js
function states_data(loc_data, selectedCountry) {
  var _states_array = [];
  var states = loc_data[selectedCountry];
  for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    _states_array.push({
      id: states[i],
      text: states[i]
    })
  }
  return _states_array
}

function _cities(state) {
  var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  return [{
    id: val + state,
    text: val + state
  }];
}
var loc_data = {
  'USA': ['USA State 1', 'USA State 2', 'USA State 3'],
  'Australia': ['AUS State 1', 'AUS State 2']
}

$('#loc_state').select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  disabled: true
}).on('change', function() {
  var selectedState = $(this).val();
  $('#loc_city').empty().select2({     // <-- empty first
    disabled: false,
    placeholder: "Select a city",
    allowClear: true,
    data: _cities(selectedState) //it should delete previous values and update new ones.
  });
}).trigger('change');

$('#loc_city').select2({
  placeholder: "Select a city",
  disabled: true
});

var countries_data = [];
for (var key in loc_data) {
  countries_data.push({
    id: key,
    text: key
  });
}

$('#loc_country').select2({
  placeholder: "Select a country",
  allowClear: true,
  data: countries_data
}).on('change', function() {
  var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
  $('#loc_state').empty().select2({        // <-- empty first
    disabled: false,
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    allowClear: true,
    data: states_data(loc_data, selectedCountry) //it should delete previous values and update new ones.
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select id="loc_country"></select>
<select id="loc_state"></select>
<select id="loc_city"></select>
```

Comment: Works like charm... I was using `$("loc_state").empty();` in separate line earlier but couldn't guess if that could be used on binding event as well. Thanks!